# Why is 'Messiah' interpreted as "a word from Allah" in the Holy Quran?

Tags: quran, tafseer, allah, prophet-isa

I read in surah Aali-Imran:45 that Messiah or Jesus is "a word from Him (Allah)." What does "a word from Allah" mean?

> إِذْ قَالَتِ الْمَلَائِكَةُ يَا مَرْ‌يَمُ إِنَّ اللَّـهَ يُبَشِّرُ‌كِ
>   بِكَلِمَةٍ مِّنْهُ اسْمُهُ الْمَسِيحُ عِيسَى ابْنُ مَرْ‌يَمَ وَجِيهًا
>   فِي الدُّنْيَا وَالْآخِرَ‌ةِ وَمِنَ الْمُقَرَّ‌بِينَ
>
> When the angels said, 'Mary, God gives thee good tidings of a Word
>   from Him whose name is Messiah, Jesus, son of Mary; high honoured
>   shall he be in this world and the next, near stationed to God.

Answer (score 1):

According to the interpretation of Allameh Muhammad-Hussein Tabatab'ee, 'word' (Arabic: *کلمة*, *kalima*) in Quranic application refers to

> '**that which shows the
>   will of Allah';** it may be an order, e.g., the word of creation when He
>   says to a thing, 'Be'; or it may be a word of revelation and
>   inspiration, etc. ([*A-Mizan Exegesis*](http://www.almizan.org/))

In this sense, Jesus was described as a "word from Allah" because he was born by Gabriel to the Holy Mary in a miraculous manner without the mediation of common natural causes; a clear manifestation of Allah's creative will.

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation you have brought is a little confusing. Please pay attention to this:

> Recall what time the angels said: Maryam! Verily Allah announced
>   unto thee a word from Him: his name Shall be the Masih, Isa, son of
>   Maryam, illustrious in the world and the Hereafter and one of those
>   brought nigh. (45)

Actually the angles brought the name of Messiah from God to Holy Maryam. The angles annunciate Holy Maryam with a son whose name was chosen by Allah.

Comment: The verse clearly indicates that Jesus is a *word* whose name is Messiah, not that there's a word, i.e. Messiah which is the name of Jesus. Word here is not used in its common meaning, i.e. verbal or literal signifier.